# Business Central, VAT amount line on sales invoice

Tags: invoice, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I would like to put VAT amount line on a sales invoice report. I created a custom report layout and added all the fields I want show on the sales invoice.

Somehow, the VatAmount_VatAmountLine works only for the first row of the booked sales invoice. This is with an iterative Line in the sales invoice.

Whenever I create a custom report layout with only the VatAmount_VatAmountLine, with an iterative VATAmountLine, it works perfectly fine.

But I need to combine those two into one table. Can somebody please explain how this works? It is hard to believe this is impossible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you working with RDLC or Word layout? In order to provide at suggestion for a possible solution an example of both dataset and layout would be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new dataitem on the report dataset, combining sales invoice lines and vat lines.

You can also try to place closely two repeater rows on the first-row print sales invoice lines on the second-row print vat lines

Why do you want to print it on the same table?